# PHPWord - Changing color of chart

Tags: php, charts, phpword

I am working with PHPWord where i have created a chart (Area) with one serie of data. As standard this is a blue serie on the chart, but i need it to be orange.

Anyone figured out how to change the color of the series? Think i have been searching everywhere without result.

```
$chart = $section->addChart($chartType, $categories, $series1);
$chart->getStyle()->setWidth(Converter::inchToEmu(6.5))->setHeight(Converter::inchToEmu(2));
```

Thanks for reading this, and especially if you got the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The phpWord chart doesn't seem to support custom color definitions.

If you can & want to modify the PhpWord code a bit yourself, here is an example how to do that for for Word2007 writer: [Define custom pie chart colors](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/issues/494)

Comment: No one figured out how to do this with a Area chart?

Answer (score 0):

you can change the color of your charts if you modify the file `PhpWord\Writer\Word2007\Part\Chart.php`.

Add this code:

```
if ($type == 'pie') 
{
    $elementColors = $this->element->getColors();

    if($elementColors !== null) 
    {
        $colorIndex = 0;
        foreach ($elementColors as $color) 
        {
            $xmlWriter->startElement('c:dPt');
                $xmlWriter->writeElementBlock('c:idx', 'val', $colorIndex);
                $xmlWriter->startElement('c:spPr');
                    $xmlWriter->startElement('a:solidFill');
                        $xmlWriter->writeElementBlock('a:srgbClr', 'val', $color);
                    $xmlWriter->endElement(); // a:solidFill
                $xmlWriter->endElement(); // c:spPr
            $xmlWriter->endElement(); // c:dPt

            $colorIndex++;
        }
    }
}
else if($type == 'area')
{
    $color = $seriesItem['color'];

    if($color!=null)
    {
        $xmlWriter->startElement('c:spPr');
            $xmlWriter->startElement('a:solidFill');
                $xmlWriter->startElement('a:srgbClr');
                    $xmlWriter->writeAttribute('val',$color);
                $xmlWriter->endElement();
            $xmlWriter->endElement();
        $xmlWriter->endElement();
    }
}
else
{
    $color = $seriesItem['color'];

    if($color!=null)
    {
        $xmlWriter->startElement('c:spPr');
            $xmlWriter->startElement('a:ln');
                $xmlWriter->writeAttribute('w', 20000);
                $xmlWriter->startElement('a:solidFill');
                    $xmlWriter->startElement('a:srgbClr');
                        $xmlWriter->writeAttribute('val',$color);
                    $xmlWriter->endElement();
                $xmlWriter->endElement();
            $xmlWriter->endElement();
        $xmlWriter->endElement();

    }   
}
```

After this other:

```
if ($scatter === true) {
    $this->writeSeriesItem($xmlWriter, 'xVal', $categories);
    $this->writeSeriesItem($xmlWriter, 'yVal', $values);
} else {
    $this->writeSeriesItem($xmlWriter, 'cat', $categories,$name);
    $this->writeSeriesItem($xmlWriter, 'val', $values);
```

You must define your color. I define this in class `PhpWord\Element\Chart.php`.

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I posted this in github issues, but posting here too just in case.  In version 0.15.0 it looks like you can change the colors with `chart->getStyle()->setColors()`:

```
$categories = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E');
$series1 = array(1, 3, 2, 5, 4);
$chartType = 'pie';
$section->addTitle(ucfirst($chartType), 2);
$chart = $section->addChart($chartType, $categories, $series1);
$chart->getStyle()->setColors( array( 'FFFFFF', '000000', 'FF0000', '00FF00', '0000FF' ) );
$chart->getStyle()->setWidth(Converter::inchToEmu(2.5))->setHeight(Converter::inchToEmu(2));
```